# How to get Playwright test result index.html on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, testing, archive, playwright

I have a freestyle project in Jenkins to run Playwright functional tests. During the build  execute shell step, I execute some Playwright functional tests. I have a setup locally that will give me the Playwright test report file `playwright-report/index.html` with this config:

```
// playwright.config.js
// @ts-check

/** @type {import('@playwright/test').PlaywrightTestConfig} */
const config = {
  reporter: [['html', {
    open: 'never',
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    port: 9223,
  }]],
};

module.exports = config;
```

I am able to open and view this file locally but I am trying to figure out how to get this file on Jenkins Job. During the build running, I was able to verify that the file `playwright-report/index.html` does get created by printing out the directory with`pwd`, which returns `root/run` . So my root/run looks like this :

```
file-A.js
file-B.js
//...other folders
playwright-report
```

And when I `cd playwright-report`, I do see `index.html` file. However, all of the files, folders under `root/run` get archived after build, except for my `playwright-report` folder.

My post-build archive artifacts set up is '**/*.*' so I expect Jenkins to archive everything. My understanding is archive artifacts step copies the selected artifacts in the `%JENKINS_HOME%/jons/MY_JOB/builds...` on the master server. And it will only archive files under my `WORKSPACE`. Is this correct ?

So I am not sure why only my `playwright-report` folder is deleted after the build and it is not archived. I tried to create a folder `playwright-dupe` during the build and then copy `playwright-report` to `playwright-dupe` during the build, but neither `playwright-dupe` nor  `playwright-folder` is archived.

So I think the directory `root/run` is different from the directory  `WORKSPACE` ? I can't find any documentation about copying a folder `from root/run` and put it in `WORKSPACE`.

Can someone help me please ? My goal is to figure out how to access that `index.html` file Playwright report generates on Jenkins with each Jenkin jobs to build functional tests. Thank you

My environment variables:

```
JENKINS_HOME:  var/lib/jenkins 
pwd: /home/jenkins/agent
WORKSPACE: home/jenkins/agent/workspace/<project-name>
```

So to sum up I tried:

- Create a duplicate folder and copy the result `playwright-report` over during build step
- Change archive set up to`dist/**, home/jenkins/agent/workspace/<project-name>/**/*.*, **/playwright-dupe`